# EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/app/current/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/chrome-linux.zip' on Elastic Beanstalk AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, puppeteer, chromium

My application deploy to Elastic beanstalk.
I install success Puppeteer, but I using code puppeteer, I get error message:

> EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/app/current/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/chrome-linux.zip

I fixed it by way:

1. chown -R $USER /var/app/current/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium

OR

2. chmod 777 /var/app/current/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium

But, every time I deploy new version. I get again above error message. And I do not want to fix by run manual two above way.

Please help me, thank you so much.